# Running QTests from CLion

Tags: qt, cmake, clion, qtestlib

Is it possible to run all QTests from the CLion Test Runner?

I have a CMake file that creates one target per Test Class, which ends up in several test targets that I can run one by one from CLion, but I haven't figured out how to run them all at once.

CMake has the "test" target, which I can build with "make test" from the test directory, but this target is not listed in CLion.

Comment: Clion is able to run the targets, which have relevant executables. Cmake's "test" targets is its own, i.e. system. It has no executable, therefore Clion cannot run it.

Comment: The "test" target is not even listed as one of the targets. Any idea how to mitigate this problem?

Comment: For example, you may write perl script, that runs "make test". Then write custom cmake target (`add_custom_target`) that runs that script. After that, you'll see the target in clion and will be able to run it. But I don't like these confusing difficulties and for me it's still way easier to manually run "make test" via console.